Images with different bounding box overlaps with each other with the same CRS
I was working with 3D point clouds and converted them into 2D images. Initially, I made an error when applying a geotransformation to the images. Specifically, I incorrectly set the top-left Y coordinate to the minimum Y value, which caused the top of the image to be smaller than the bottom. For example, my bounding box was:
BoundingBox(left=566000.003, bottom=5937064.004, right=566064.003, top=5937000.004)

After identifying this mistake, I corrected the code by setting the top-left Y to the maximum Y value, which properly adjusted the image extent. The corrected bounding box became:
BoundingBox(left=569001.1, bottom=5935804.5, right=569010.5, top=5935816.4)

However, when I compared the original incorrect image with the corrected one in QGIS, both images still overlapped perfectly. I also checked using the polygon of the images, and the polygons overlapped as well, even with the incorrect image. Bounding box of the polygon.
minx             miny            maxx           maxy
569001.00299    5.935804e+06    569010.502895   5.935816e+06



Although I've fixed the mistake in my code, I'm still seeing that both the incorrect and corrected images overlap perfectly in QGIS. I’m wondering if anyone might have an explanation for this or if someone else has faced a similar issue.

How did you convert a 3D point cloud into a 2D image?
